How does Mono enable ETL files to capture both native and managed call stacks?
I am conducting a research project and have encountered an issue with an older version of Mono (a modified version used in Unity, around 2015-2016, exact version unknown). When using a profiling tool to generate ETL files, the managed call stacks were not visible. However, after an update around 2017, the managed call stacks became visible. How was this achieved?
The profiling tool seems to gather all necessary information solely from the ETL file and the executable being profiled.
I believe that the call stack information in the ETL files primarily comes from the MSNT_SystemTrace's StackWalk event (other events provide details like function names, but they are not crucial for my query).
I attempted to retrieve the PID of the process associated with this provider using Windows APIs, but the result was -1, which I don't understand.
I suspect there might have been changes in the newer versions of Mono or its dependencies that could affect the recording of this event, but I haven't found any differences after extensive searching.
I'm unsure if other providers and events play a role in the visualization of the call stacks, but my preliminary review suggests they likely do not.
Additional context: I found in the .NET Framework update logs that version 4.0 introduced some performance testing support, but I'm not sure if the specific changes affect the phenomenon I observed or if they impact Mono at all. Here is the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms171868(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN
Here is the test code I used(v2.0.50215 for old version,v4.0.30319 for new version):
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mono mono;
    char hello[] = "helloworld.exe";
    char* path[1] = { hello };
    MonoAssembly* assembly;
    MonoDomain* domain;
    getchar();

    puts(argv[0]);
    mono_api_init(&mono,".\\mono-2.0-bdwgc.dll");
    //mono_api_init(&mono, ".\\mono-2.0.dll");
    mono.set_assemblies_path(".\\lib");
    //domain = mono.jit_init_version("myapp", "v4.0.30319");
    domain = mono.jit_init_version("myapp", "v2.0.50215");
    if (!domain)
    {
        puts("err1");
        return -1;
    }

    getchar();
    assembly = mono.domain_assembly_open(domain, "helloworld.exe");
    puts("3");
    getchar();

    if (!assembly)
    {
        puts("err2");
        return -1;
    }
    mono.jit_exec(domain, assembly, 1, path);
}

Here are some screenshots from my tests:
old version
new version
One of the StackWalk event(new version):
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
        <Provider Guid="{9e814aad-3204-11d2-9a82-006008a86939}" />
        <EventID>0</EventID>
        <Version>2</Version>
        <Level>0</Level>
        <Task>0</Task>
        <Opcode>32</Opcode>
        <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-09-12T15:41:09.231603300+07:59" />
        <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
        <Execution ProcessID="4294967295" ThreadID="4294967295" ProcessorID="2" KernelTime="0" UserTime="0" />
        <Channel />
        <Computer />
    </System>
    <EventData>
        <Data Name="EventTimeStamp">5915705958622</Data>
        <Data Name="StackProcess">0x8BDC</Data>
        <Data Name="StackThread">   19588</Data>
        <Data Name="Stack1">0x77E31CF3</Data>
        <Data Name="Stack2">0x77E31CB4</Data>
        <Data Name="Stack3">0x77E31D75</Data>
        <Data Name="Stack4">0x7FFEFEE4EA8D</Data>
        <Data Name="Stack5">0x7FFEFEE4E18D</Data>
        <Data Name="Stack6">0x7FFF0112E57B</Data>
        <Data Name="Stack7">0x7FFF0111A86E</Data>
        <Data Name="Stack8">0x7FFF010C4383</Data>
        <Data Name="Stack9">0x7FFF010C42AE</Data>
        <Data Name="Stack10">0x7687122C</Data>
        <Data Name="Stack11">0x7A6FED10</Data>
        <Data Name="Stack12">0x7A64E138</Data>
        <Data Name="Stack13">0x7A64DBF3</Data>
        <Data Name="Stack14">0x7A6EF37E</Data>
        <Data Name="Stack15">0x7A6FBD77</Data>
        <Data Name="Stack16">0x7A6DCDFD</Data>
        <Data Name="Stack17">0x24A3480</Data>
        <Data Name="Stack18">0x3BC0447</Data>
        <Data Name="Stack19">0x7A6E52E7</Data>
        <Data Name="Stack20">0x77C53773</Data>
        <Data Name="Stack21">0x77C44596</Data>
        <Data Name="Stack22">0x77C43F07</Data>
        <Data Name="Stack23">0x7A6D9192</Data>
        <Data Name="Stack24">0x77C53773</Data>
        <Data Name="Stack25">0x77C44596</Data>
        <Data Name="Stack26">0x77C42E55</Data>
        <Data Name="Stack27">0x77C429A0</Data>
        <Data Name="Stack28">0x7A6FE642</Data>
        <Data Name="Stack29">0x3D9EA8A</Data>
        <Data Name="Stack30">0x3D9E7E6</Data>
        <Data Name="Stack31">0x3958E36</Data>
        <Data Name="Stack32">0x58AB93F</Data>
        <Data Name="win:ExtraPayload" Type="win:ErrorMoreData">0xA97BE275000000000BC1EA77000000008FC0EA7700000000</Data>
    </EventData>
    <RenderingInfo Culture="zh-CN">
        <Opcode>Stack</Opcode>
        <Provider>MSNT_SystemTrace</Provider>
        <EventName xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">StackWalk</EventName>
    </RenderingInfo>
    <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
        <EventGuid>{def2fe46-7bd6-4b80-bd94-f57fe20d0ce3}</EventGuid>
    </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>

Could anyone provide insights into how Mono was updated to support visibility of managed call stacks in ETL files, or point me towards any relevant changes or documentation?

For JITed code there needs to be a .NET Runtime provider running inside the mono runtime to emit the mapping tables of method address range and their method name. Without that data you will not get managed stack traces. Check out Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntimeRundown provider with event MethodDCEndVerbose.

Firstly, I apologize for the delayed response due to a series of non-working days.
Thank you for your guidance on resolving the issue with ETL files in Mono. I've attempted to follow your advice by looking for the Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntimeRundown provider in the ETL files, but unfortunately, I couldn't find it. Instead, I found a provider named Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntime. Additionally, I did not find any events named MethodDCEndVerbose.

I did come across some events named ThreadDCEnd and ImageDCEnd, but these were provided by MSNT_SystemTrace. This observation was consistent across ETL files recorded with both versions of Mono, and it seems to have no impact on the stack trace display.
Could you please provide further assistance?Thank you for your continued support.

The Rundown provider is nearly the same as the Runtime provider, but it can be enabled additionally during trace stop to emit the MethodDC... events. The Thread and image events are needed for other purposes, but these are only indirectly relevant for method name resolution. If Mono does not use these events then a generated pdb would need to exist, but if this is JITed code the pdb cannot contain the mapping between JITed method addresses and the corresponding method. How stack resolution is exactly done can be read by checking the source code of PerfView which is open source.
